# Onclick element of Submit Button Not Calling JS Function

Tags: javascript, php, html, onclick

Hi I'm familiar with using onsubmit and onclick as I have used them before, but for some reason it refuses to work this time around. I've looked at my old code and tried everything to make it exactly the same yet it still will not run.

```js
function verifypass()
{
var password = "Testpass";
var string = document.getElementByID("verifybadge");
if(string!=password) {
alert("Wrong password!");
window.location="about:blank";
}
}
```

```html
<form name="receivingform" method="post">
</br></br>
<b>Please Enter Password to Verify Closure of Ticket: </b> </br>
<input type="text" size="15" maxlength="20" id="verifybadge"> </br>
<input class="button_text" type="submit" value="Delete Closed Rows"      onclick="verifypass();">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Man, it's [document.getElementById](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp)
by the way, let's clean that code:

HTML:

```
<form name="receivingform" method="post">
    <br/><br/>
    <b>Please Enter Password to Verify Closure of Ticket: </b> <br/>
    <input type="text" size="15" maxlength="20" id="verifybadge" /> <br/>
    <input class="button_text" type="submit" value="Delete Closed Rows" onclick="verifypass()" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function verifypass() {
    var password = "Testpass";
    var string = document.getElementById("verifybadge").value;
    if(string !== password) {
        alert("Wrong password!");
        window.location="about:blank";
    }
}
```

This code works
(notice the .value as suggested by @John)

*Under here a snippet:*

```js
function verifypass() {
  var password = "Testpass";
  var string = document.getElementById("verifybadge").value;
  if(string !== password) {
    alert("Wrong password!");
    //window.location="about:blank";
  } else alert("yay");
}
```

```html
<form name="receivingform" method="post">
  <br/><br/>
  <b>Please Enter Password to Verify Closure of Ticket: </b> <br/>
  <input type="text" size="15" maxlength="20" id="verifybadge" /> <br/>
  <input class="button_text" type="button" value="Delete Closed Rows" onclick="verifypass()" />
</form>
```

Comment: Guess its going to be one of those days. Happy Monday everyone

Comment: @AggieEngr, You could've simply debugged this in the console.

Comment: As it was displayed, I am pretty new to this @Mouser. Thanks for the heads up though, I'll use the console from now on

Comment: Hey now even if I submit the right password, the alert is still popping up saying its the wrong password. Any ideas?

Comment: try modifying `!=` to `!==` so it results: `if(string !== password)`

Comment: the `document.getElementByID("verifybadge");` returns "element". You need to check for `.value` of the given element to get the content of the input.

Comment: Anyhow if the password shall have a bit of security, do not use such simple javascript. This way the password can be simply visible in the source code.

Comment: It doesn't really need to be secure, but I appreciate it. However, I tried changing it both ways you and @Tommy suggested and it still isnt working